# Android Studio - Tag Mismatch error even after trying everything else that I have read in other posts with the same problem

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download protos-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.1.1/protos-27.1.1.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.72)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.72/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
```

Hello, I have been trying to make android studio work but I keep getting error after error :( Right now I have this one (I just created the project) and it happens every time. I have tried manually installing the graddle, uninstalling android studio, toggling offline mode, which resulted in this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download protos-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.1): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.72): No cached version available for offline mode

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

And almost everything else that I have read in other posts from people who had a similar problem. Is there anything that I could do to make android studio work for me? :(

Thanks for reading this.